# VB.Net "COMException was unhandled" Error

Tags: vb.net, comexception

I have a VB.Net program written with .Net 2.0
I'm trying to write a code that logs entire registry entries into a log file.
I have got it to work wit the following code.
http://pastebin.com/kmA63cUe
However whenever I try to add an additional Registry key to log

```
LogPrint4("<-----------------HKLM/WebCheck-------------------->")
    If reg.enumvalues(&H8000002, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WebCheck", keys2, types) = 0 Then
        If IsArray(keys2) Then
            For p = 0 To UBound(keys2)
                reg.getstringvalue(&H8000002, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WebCheck", keys2(p), value)
                LogPrint4(keys2(p) & "=" & value)
            Next
        End If
    End If
```

It comes up with the following error

> COMException was unhandled Check the ErrorCode Property of the
> exception to determine the HRESULT returned by the COM object.

I'm not sure why it is limiting it only to 5 checks.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you certain that the key actually exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the built-in Registry support instead of the COM libraries.  At a minimum, you'll get clearer error messages.  It is supported in .NET 2.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.80).aspx

Good luck!

Comment: Great!  If this solved your problem, please "Accept" the answer by clicking over to the left of the answer.